# How to Count consecutive value and after count of 3 change the status as required

Tags: sql

I have a table as below

```
    create table #pp (BrandID int, Axis int, Metric int)

insert into #pp values
(32,1, 0),
(32,2, 0),
(32,3, 1),
(32,4, 1),
(32,5, 1),
(32,6, 1),
(32,7, 1),
(32,8, 1),
(32,9, 1),
(32,10, 0)
```

I want to count value in 'Metric' column and after 3 consecutive value of 1, change Status to 1,2,3. For example as shown as below

[image]

I am not getting the expected result, please help

[image]

Comment: please refer to the screenshot attached

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  The key idea is to subtract an enumerated value from `axis` to define the groups of adjacent values.  Then, use arithmetic to calculate the status:

```
select t.*,
       (case when metric = 1 
             then ( row_number() over (partition by metric, axis - seqnum order by axis) + 2 ) / 3
             else 0
        end) as status
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by metric order by axis) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by axis;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61fece63d5f9d579942d5000adbc5758) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, the solution is really good, however, this works until a value in Metric comes back to 0, that breaks the consecutiveness* . Then when the Metric value is 1 again, the status is not 3, hope that makes sense. Please see a screenshot

Comment: Please refer to the second screenshot above

Comment: @mbajrach . . . The code is fine if you set up the data correctly:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb5db74c684217e05f917e63f51b0527.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is really useful.